# SQL Update statement using aggregate function causing error

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I tried many solutions with no fortune.  Someone please help

**Table_1**:

```
car_type date_purchased  down_payment
-------------------------------------
toyota    2/2012             $100
honda     4/2012             $500
ford      5/2012             $235
toyota    1/2013             $400
honda     4/2013             $20
```

**Final_table** (should look like this):

```
car_type  date      final_cost
--------------------------------
toyota    3/2012      $100
honda     4/2012      $500
ford      12/2012     $235
```

The final table should be created like this:

```
update final_table
set final_cost = table_1.down_payment 
where final_table.car_type = table1.car_type 
  and max(table_1.date_purchased) <= final_table.date
```

The cost should be the cost from the `max(date_purchased)` that is less than or equal to the `final_table.date`

But SQL Server does not like the max and <= part.

It keeps saying to add having and group by but they don't work

Does anyone know how to get the code to work?

Gracias

Comment: You should _always_ post the error and details on why it 'doesn't work'

Comment: sql server kept stating that because i had an aggregate max() that i had to use having and when i added 'having' it would still complain. I searched and  tried all the solutions i saw in stackoverflow but nothing worked

Comment: Your question would be easier to answer if you showed us both current and desired output.

Comment: It may seem that I'm being picky, and you probably already have correct answers below but you really need to post the exact error message, and "would still complain" is no an error message. You already have answers below but perhaps next time make sure you post the actual error messages

Comment: I kept getting 'could not be bound' errors with these answers. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend:

```
update ft
    set final_cost = t1.down_payment 
    from final_table ft outer apply
         (select top 1 t1.*
          from table_1 t1
          where t1.car_type = ft.car_type and
                t1.date_purchased <= ft.date
          order by t1.date_purchased desc
         ) t1;
```

Comment: This seems to be working! and you used aliases!! thank you so much, i spent 3 days trying to figure this out.  it seems simple but it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update final_table
set final_cost = table_1.down_payment 
where final_table.car_type = table1.car_type 
and final_table.date > (
  select max(date_purchased) from table_1)
```

Comment: I tried this and sql server printed 'table1.car_type could not be bound'

Answer (score 0):

You can't use aggregate functions in where ! use group by with having.

```
update final_table
set final_cost = table_1.down_payment 
where final_table.car_type = table1.car_type 
and table_1.date_purchased in (select table_1.date_purchased from table_1 
 group by table_1.date_purchased
 having (max(table_1.date_purchased) <= final_table.date)
 )
```

Comment: I tried this and the messages 'table1.car_type could not be bound' and 'table1.date_purchased could not be bound' happened.